# Scala Playframework 2.2 - HtmlUnit missing

Tags: scala, playframework, htmlunit, playframework-2.2

I have a project using Playframework 2.2

I eclipsified it and in my code I write something like this:

```
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient    

val client = new WebClient
```

Eclipse says everything's fine, but when I `play run` my application I get a following message:

```
[error] C:\workspace\kwiket\kwiketscala\app\service\parsers\HTMLParser.scala:11: object gargoylesoftware is not a member of package com
[error] import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient
```

How could I fix this? What dependencies should I add to my project? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the test configuration is HTMLUnit available, but you need it in the compile configuration.

Just update your libraryDependencies in build.sbt:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  jdbc,
  anorm,
  cache,
  "net.sourceforge.htmlunit" % "htmlunit" % "2.13" //found on http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cnet.sourceforge.htmlunit%7Chtmlunit%7C2.13%7Cjar section SBT
)
```

Restart SBT or execute `reload`.